# Override error_log from /etc/php-fpm.conf in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, php-fpm

I need to configure the file for PHP's `error_log` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.

---

Everything works perfectly fine when using:

`/etc/php-fpm.conf`:

```
;error_log = /var/log/wrong-file.log
```

`/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
error_log = /var/log/correct-file.log
```

---

But logs are written to `/var/log/wrong-file.log` when using:

`/etc/php-fpm.conf`:

```
error_log = /var/log/wrong-file.log
```

`/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
error_log = /var/log/correct-file.log
```

---

After all I've read the `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` should override values in `/etc/php-fpm.conf` or is that wrong?